# show a form in a popup when a button is pressed

Tags: forms, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I am creating  a registration form it has multiple stages. I am able to redirect to another page with the help of a link. 
How can i get the form as a popup with a button.

```
 $form['adding_disease']=array( 
   '#markup'=> '<a href ="nojs">'.t('disease_list').'</a>', 
 );
```

Here this snippet is written in a form with many other fields.
this link is in the middle of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [Ctools Automodal](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) module. This approach is less complicated to @Web-Beest answer.

Here is the example on how to use it.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/form'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
    'modal' => TRUE, 
  );
}
```

The most important line in the above code is `'modal' => TRUE,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTools Modal window for this.

First you need to add a path to your hook_menu() which will call the modal function.

```
$items['your_path'] = array(
  'title' => 'Do modal popup',
  'page callback' => 'module_form_modal',
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Then you can create the function which will do the magic. The 'ctools_modal_form_wrapper' will wrap the form so it can be loaded in the modal.

```
function module_form_modal() {
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');

  $form_state = array(
    'ajax' => TRUE,
    'title' => '',
    'build_info' => array('args' => array()),
  );
  $commands = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('YOUR_FORM_NAME', $form_state);
  if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
    $commands = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
  }
  print ajax_render($commands);
}
```

Then you need to add a ctools button in your form so it knows to use the modal.

```
$link = ctools_modal_text_button($text, 'your_path', $alt, $class);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
$form['adding_disease']=array(
'#markup'=>'<a  href="path/nojs" class=" ctools-use-modal" >'.t('click here').'</a>'
);
```

and don't forget to include the below three lines in the callback, before calling the form.

```
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
ctools_include('ajax');
```